# Is there any difference in read count when fetching 10 items in one call vs 2 item in 5 calls when using cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any difference between these two kind of fetching when it comes to read count in Cloud firestore?

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
    .limit(10)
    .snapshots();
```

vs

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collection")
    .startAfter(lastDocument)
    .orderBy('field')
    .limit(2)
    .snapshots();
```

In first part, I am fetching 10 documents all at once, in 2nd part, I am fetching only 2 documents at a time but calling it 5 times to get those same 10 documents, starting after the last fetched document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the two calls as far as reading is concerned because read count is considered for every document you read by making API call.

Since in both the cases, you're only reading the document 10 times, you'll be charged for 10 read calls.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that in the 2nd case your security rules will be ran 5 times instead of 1 and depending on how they are written it could cost you more reads.

Comment: I didn't know that, can you please post a link for reference?